# Understanding the use of Radial Basis Function in Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, machine-learning, radial-basis-functions

I am attempting to understand the use of Radial Basis Functions (RBFs) as used in linear regression.

**Building the problem**:

RBFs can be used as a means of separating data which is not linearly separable (see example scatter-plot by link containing different below)

[Non-linearly separable Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcUBq.png)

Positive (green) and negative (red) data-points are clustered together but no straight line can be found to separate them from each-other.

We are seeking some function $f(x) = w\phi(x) + c$ which will plot a 'line' between the points. 
**Note**:

- $w$ represents a matrix of weights
- $\phi(x) = \exp(−(x−c)^⊤(x−c)/h^2)$ (**Note**: Our Radial Basis function is Gaussian).
- $c$ is our 'y' intercept
- $h$ relates to how quickly $\phi(x)$ drops off towards zero

**My current "understanding"**:

We can use a linear combination of RBFs (a seperate RBF for each cluster, 3 in this case) to find a 'line' ( $f(x)$ ) which will separate positive data-points from negative data-points.

The function will appear as follows:

$f(x) = w_1\phi_1(x) + w_2\phi_2(x) + w_3\phi_3(x)$

So we choose values for centers $c_1, c_2, c_3$ to offset the respective RBFs $\phi_1(x), \phi_2(x), \phi_3(x)$ according to the distance the related scatter plot is from the origin of the 2-d plane ($x_1$,$x_2$).

Appropriate values are then chosen for the $w_1, w_2, w_3$ matrix such that when multiplied by the respective $\phi$ the hope being that any new (previously unseen values) will be determined to be positive or negative depending on what side of the 'line' defined by $f(x)$ they reside on.

**My Questions**:

1. Am I correct, incorrect, partially correct in my current understanding?
2. If correct are there things you feel I am leaving out?
3. If incorrect, why?
4. If partially correct, could you advise what is right or wrong?

Comment: It is a way to increase the dimensionality which hopefully bends the space giving more room for a linear decision boundary to be placed.

Comment: Thanks but I understand that, we are introducing an additional dimension such that we can find a line to separate the positive and negative clusters. But I am more concerned about the thought processes (described in the question), I.e. how the mathematics actually works.

Comment: Then I think it is a good idea to experiment. Make computer programs do it and see what happens when you play around with it. Then you will gradually build up an understanding for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will do this time permitting, if anyone else feels like commenting then please do. I will be keeping an eye on this and it may also help others in the future. I will endeavor to run some programs to tease out my  understanding and hopefully post my findings here for future readers.